# Heroku CLI update available... or not?

Tags: macos, heroku, homebrew, heroku-cli

A bit weird... Any thoughts?

```
% heroku -v
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.68.2 to 8.0.1.
heroku/7.68.2 darwin-x64 node-v14.19.0
% brew upgrade heroku
Warning: heroku/brew/heroku 7.68.2 already installed
```

Answer (score 14):

Just run `heroku update` - looks like it doesn't upgrade through homebrew at this time.